# App Rejected: No InApp-Purchases available - How to set up Sandbox InApp-Purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My app was rejected because my InApp-Purchases are not displayed inside the app (obviously because my app binary wasn't accepted yet). I have a page, where you can "get premium" but the buy button with the corresponding prices will only be available once the InApp-Purchases has been approved.

I was told I need to make sure, the InApp-Purchases are available at the time of review. I was also told "You can learn more about how to set up and test In App Purchase products in your development sandbox environment in the Test User Setup for In App Purchase Section of the iTunes Connect Developer Guide".

However I could not find information on how to set up a sandbox InApp Purchases. I was able to create a sandbox test account, which I signed in on my device. But that doesn't change the face, that my InApp-Purchases are not available.

Is there actually a way to set up Sandbox InApp-Purchases, that don't need approval? What am I missing here?

Comment: The IAPs are available during testing even though they haven't been approved. You must submit them for approval at the same time as you submit your first build with IAP functionality. Make sure your paid application agreement and tax and banking set up is complete.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the help! My IAPs have the status "Waiting For Review" and the App has the Status "Rejected". The IAPs aren't available. I just filled out the tax and banking set up and its in "Active (Pending User Info)". What could I be missing?

Comment: It sounds like your paperwork isn't complete. Pending review is ok, but if your paper work isn t complete in tax and banking then you won't get the products from the skproductrequest

Comment: @Paulw11 I got that resolved now, It is now "Active" for both Paid and Free Apps but the IAPs are still not available

Comment: Are you testing on a real device (not simulator)?  Have you got the correct IAP identifier(s)?  Are you checking the invalid product identifiers that are returned to your product request handler?